# How can I escape a \n from an html-attribute to a js-string?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass new-lines from a html-attribute to a javascriptstring, in order to apply it to a textarea:

```
<input id="check input" type="checkbox" data-mode2="Varför är det så mycket administration! \n\n">Mer tid att lägga på att träffa barn, istället för administration</input>

string = $('#check').data('hello'+mode);
$('textarea').val(string);
```

This outputs the \n as characters rather than a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Define the data format you are using
2. Parse that data format

You could say the data format is "Plain text except that new lines are expressed as `\n`".

In which case you could use a simple regular expression replacement.

```
var parsed_string = string.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
```

---

You might be better off using an existing language, like JSON, which would give you more options in the future and come with prebuilt parsers.

```js
var mode = "mode2";
var string = $('#check').data(mode);
var parsed_string = JSON.parse(string);
$('textarea').val(parsed_string);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input id="check" type="checkbox" data-mode2="&quot;Varför är det så mycket administration! \n\n&quot;">Mer tid att lägga på att träffa barn, istället för administration</label>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Note that I had to wrap the data in `"` characters to make it a valid JSON string.

Comment: neat! How can I add the &quot; in javascript, I tried string = "&quot;"

Comment: `"\""` or `'"'` … but adding them in JS misses the point of using JSON in the first place. If your data in in the JS already, just use a JavaScript string. You only need to parse it if you are pulling it from somewhere outside the JS program (like the DOM).