# How can I json.parse a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse a string that is created from data I get from html.

```
    var string = ''
    string += '\n\n\n';
    string += $('#tickmarks').data('hello'+mode);
    string += '\n';
    checks.forEach(function(check){
        if($(check).is(':checked')){
            string += $(check).parent().text();
            string += '\n\n';
        }
    });
    string += $('#tickmarks').data('goodbye'+mode);

    string += '\n';

    string += $('.name').val();
    $('textarea').val(JSON.parse(string));
```

I get errors, when I try to pass characters into this string. Apparently a string in JSON should have quotes, I have tried adding them like this:

```
string += '"'
string += "foo"
string += '"'
```

and this:

```
string += '&quot;'
string += "foo"
string += '&quot;'
```

and this:

```
string += "'"
string += "foo"
string += "'"
```

Comment: Trying to parse a json string? `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Don't do that.  You should build an object and use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: what should the object look like?

Comment: What you are looking for might reside in [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function. I don't think manually building a JSON object (through strings) is a good idea.

Comment: The reason i'm doing this in the first place is so that I can pass \n from html for newlines...

Comment: @Himmators: `JSON.stringify()` handles all values.  _You should use it_.

Comment: As I said when you asked this as a comment on [my answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950319/19068): Don't do this. If you are going to use JSON as your data format, then make sure you write JSON in the first place. Writing invalid JSON and then mangling it to make it valid before parsing it JS is a **terrible** idea.

Comment: As others have said, use JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() as appropriate.  Insert the new lines and any other manipulations while writing out your json object.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are not necessary.
For example this string is easily parseable without additional quotes in it:

```
> JSON.parse('\n\n{}');
< Object {}
```

However, if you want to have JSON representation of some jQuery objects, I suggest building a Object from your jQuery selection and then using JSON.stringify()

```
    var data = {
       {tickmarks:$('#tickmarks').data('hello'+mode)}     
    };
    checks.forEach(function(check){
        if($(check).is(':checked')){
                data[$(check).parent().text()] = $(check).parent().text();
            }
        });
    JSON.stringify(data);
```

PS. In your code you should try to print the concatenated string and verify that it follows the rules for parsing string (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples)